# How can I update an entity without having and updating its associated entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**Background**

In my Spring Boot application using Spring Data JPA, I have a `Car` entity with an *many-to-one relationship* to a `Make` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Car {

   @Id
   private Long id;
   
   @ManyToOne
   private Make make;

} 

@Entity
public class Make {

   @Id
   private Long id;

   private String description;

}
```

I have two clients that need to update a `Car` entity.

- One client will have the associated `Make` instance.
- The second client will not have the associated `Make` instance. It will **not even have the id of the associated `Make` instance**.

**Desired behavior**

When *client 1* passes in a `Car` with non-null `Make` instance, I want to update the association (if changed) to the `Make` instance. This works now. Client 1 will never pass in null for `Make` but if it did, my application can behave like the client 2 desired behavior below.

*Client 2* will always have null for the associated `Make`. I want to simply keep the association (i.e., same foreign key) as before the update.

**Question**

Using JPA (or some Hibernate / Spring Data JPA specific way), how can I have the foreign key (`makeId`) to `make` in the `Car` table remain unchanged when null is passed in for the `make` field of `Car`?

**What I've tried / researched**

I've read other posts that indicate that having the id of the associated entity can be used without requiring a query of the associated entity. However, client 2 doesn't provide the `id` for `Make`. After all, it doesn't care about updating `Make`.

I know that I can set `updateable` to false on the `Make` relationship. However, this will not work for me since client 1 will need to update this relationship.

**Additional Info**

One other note is that `makeId` fk doesn't permits null. So a null for `make` will never mean to set `makeId` to null.

**Update**

For now, I'm just loading the associated entity (see below code). But hoping that someone will offer a better solution.

Spring JPA Data Repository:

```
public interface CarRepository extends CrudRepository<Car, Long> {

  @Query("select c.make "
        + "from Car c "
        + "where c.id = :id")
  Make findMakeByCarId(@Param("carId") Long carId);
}
```

*Client 2* save of car:

```
Make make = carRepository.findMakeByCarId(client2Car.getId());
client2Car.setMake(make);
carRepository.save(client2Car);
```

Comment: Make updateable=false.If not null getMakeEntity.’Session.save(makeEntity);Session.save(carEntity; surrounded by same transaction’

Comment: And atlast could use query for one case and entityManager for other.(Using mobile ,sorry for typos)

Comment: @Sagar - Thanks for your comments. I prefer to stay using Spring Data JPA calls and not use specific Hibernate calls, but I will if that is the only way.

Comment: Null is valid state for entities, so if you want to send null values (via REST or other mechanisms) and have it interpreted as something else (ie do nothing), then you have to handle merging your data into the Entity yourself. Read in the entity, and if it exists merge in your changed data as you require and just don't touch properties that are null. If the value is non-null, you don't need to read in the entity. JPA should accept the 'make' instance and just use the ID for the foreign key without changing it as long as you don't have cascade merge/persist on the relationship.